# React/Vue (Or any other similar framework) MPA implementation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vue.js, single-page-application, multi-page-application

I am new to React and Vue frameworks. I am learning how to build simple SPA from courses, but there are no courses for MPA/SPA.

For example when I need website with 3 parts: Registration form, Login form, Dashboard

I don't want to use SPA and Router. I want to have those 3 sections served by back-end as 3 different websites. If you asking why, it is because I see this technique on almost every React/Vue powered websites (Instagram, AirBnB, Qualitista, ...)

Can you please explain to me what is best practice and how to implement this and if its worth making? Or am I supposed to just make backend API + SPA no matter what.

Comment: Airbnb is using what we would call a universal SPA app. And are definetly using some kind of router

Comment: @Borjante That was not my question. My question is how to make app what is sometimes SPA sometimes MPA (For example when you click "settings" in Airbnb, site refresh.. What means its not SPA)

Comment: We'll with VueJS, If you choose to use a normal <a> tag instead of a <router-link> the page will refresh

Comment: Companies use server-side rendering or preloading to bypass the limitations of Vue with regard to SEO. Google cannot crawl Vue components, so serving them from the server allows them to be indexed before rendering. There are guides on this on YouTube and Udemy, and it's definitely an advanced technique.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about this topic in particular.  But after a little searching, this [Universal Multi-Page React App](https://www.sandersdenardi.com/universal-multi-page-react/) looks like it might be a tutorial to do what you're interested in? Also found a little info in this Reddit post about [Multi-page React Sites](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/7ymuk6/multipage_react_sites/).

Also here's some info about how Vue.js does it from **I'mOnlyVueman** with a couple articles I found on the topic.

> Companies use server-side rendering or preloading to bypass the
> limitations of Vue with regard to SEO. Google cannot crawl Vue
> components, so serving them from the server allows them to be indexed
> before rendering.

- [Vue.js Server Side Rendering Guide](https://ssr.vuejs.org/)
- [Server Side Rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html) from the Vue.js docs

If you were to ask me a good example to learn multiple page apps I wouldn't go to React/Vue to do this, I'd use MVC.  Microsoft has tons of tutorials if you're interested.  [Create a web app with ASP.Net Core and MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Google does crawl JS-rendered SPAs now.

Comment: @RoyJ Have you any source for that? Last time I checked it was not 100% reliable, sometimes he did index JS content, sometimes he didn't

Comment: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/10/updating-our-technical-webmaster.html
> For optimal rendering and indexing, our new guideline specifies that you should allow Googlebot access to the JavaScript, CSS, and image files that your pages use. This provides you optimal rendering and indexing for your site.

Comment: More: http://www.thesempost.com/google-indexes-ranks-javascript-pages-two-waves-days-apart/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are referring to is called Micro Frontends https://micro-frontends.org but just like Micro Services, it is a solution to an organisational problem, not a technical one.

If you are not Instagram or Airbnb, you'll save yourself a lot of extra work by sticking with a monolithic architecture.

Next.js is a good place to start if you want to be guided into the pit of success https://nextjs.org